How to use otel collector to collect some CRD resources?
Does there are any solutions that I can use to collect resources for Operators, Helm Charts, CRD hierarchies and CD configurations via otel collector? All of them are not build-in resources for Kubernetes but kind of CRD resource, does there are any option that I can collect those info via otel? Thanks
Want to get some solution to collect above kubernetes CRD resources via otel

The k8sobjectreceiver in the collector may do what you want here [0]. It can be used to pull kubernetes manifests based on its configuration:
  k8sobjects:
    auth_type: serviceAccount
    objects:
      - name: <resource-name>
        group: <resource-group>
        mode: pull
        label_selector: environment in (production),tier in (frontend)
        field_selector: status.phase=Running
        interval: 15m

You should be able to use this by specifying the resource name and group to pull down. You would then use this receiver in a logs pipeline.
[0] https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/k8sobjectsreceiver

Thanks @jaronoff97! Yes, I saw this repo and want to do some test, but seems it is not working, due to the image cannot be pulled off, https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/issues/32909#issuecomment-2098811238 , any suggestion for this? Thanks

@GuangyaLiu you seem to be pulling the incorrect image, be sure to use the image from the releases page: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-releases/pkgs/container/opentelemetry-collector-releases%2Fopentelemetry-collector-contrib
